# What is the definition of a non-blank character in Vim?

Tags: vim

Launch vim.
In the empty buffer, insert two lines where the first line consists of 3 spaces and the second line consists of `hello world`.

Here is an example file where the spaces are represented with dots.

```
...
hello world
```

Now press `gg`. The cursor moves to the third space of the first line.

Quoting `:help gg`:

```
<C-Home>    or                  *gg* *<C-Home>*
gg          Goto line [count], default first line, on the first
            non-blank character |linewise|.  If 'startofline' not
            set, keep the same column.
```

The documentation says that the cursor should move to the first non-blank character of the first line. I have two questions.

1. Does `:help` document the definition of a non-blank character? If so, could you please point me to it?
2. Is the behaviour that we observe in the experiment mentioned above consistent with the documentation provided in `:help gg`?

Comment: Seems like the behavior could be a side-effect of `gg`'s implementation.  And I don't think the docs explicitly define "non-blank" because it's understood that "blank" refers to space (ASCII 32) or tab (9) characters.

Comment: `:helpgrep non-blank`.

Comment: @romainl I did `:helpgrep non-blank` and then `:cnext` many times but I failed to find where non-blank is defined. Could you please point me to the help file where non-blank is defined?

Comment: It doesn't have its own chapter but you can find a mention on line 288 of `:help pattern.txt`. It's 51 `:cnext` away, BTW. But my point is that you can search yourself abit deeper before asking for help.

Comment: @romainl Okay, I see this in line 282 of `:h pattern.txt`: `The WORD may contain any non-blanks (<Tab>s and/or <Space>s).` I did dig deep before asking for help but I didn't know how much deeper to dig.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a *general* definition of non-blank in the vim docs, but I also do not believe this is a "side effect" of `gg`.

Note that `gg` is consistent here with `^`:

```
^          To the first non-blank character of the line.           
           |exclusive| motion.
```

and `[:blank:]` of vim's pattern matching behavior (`:h blank`) defines blank characters as space and tab:

```
*[:blank:]*               [:blank:]     space and tab characters
```

As far as whether or not this is consistent with `gg`, consider what it says it will do as two steps instead of one:

1. Go to the first line (default since no count was specified) -- it does this.
2. Go to the first non-blank character of said line.

Probably the easiest way to implement 2 as an algorithm is to position the cursor **after all the blank characters at the beginning of the line**. In your case, they are all blank characters (and it cannot move to the next line), so the cursor is positioned at the end of the line (after all the blank characters).